# Site speed slows when user logged in

Tags: cache, iis

my wp site is hosted on an IIS windows server. Issue is, my ttfb when a user is logged in is a lot longer (2/3 seconds) then when no user is logged in (super fast). See this video for a demo:

https://youtu.be/uMJs9v0LqPM

I've tried many different permutations of cache plugins/settings (W3 TC and WP Super Cache) and iis settings, and I don't think it's down to that. Also, the amber warnings through Query Monitor are only a matter of miliseconds. I disabled any user manager plugins for this demo of the problem.

I have tried disabling the 'do not use cache for logged in users' for both cache plugins, but this didn't seem to make any difference.

I'm just really curios about the difference. I can't figure why the loading times are so disparate depending on whether a user is logged on or not....

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks a lot like caching. What does the network tab in your browser developer tools like like in each case? Do you have a way to look at CPU usage on your server in each case? This would be a way to see for sure if the server's doing a lot of work to render the page or not in each case. What if you deactivate caching completely?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes - i think it is caching. I'm using WP Super Cache with "Disable caching for logged in visitors" turned off as this is recompensed. Logged out: ttfb = 37ms (cached). Logged in ttfb=3.18s!! I did observe my CPU and yes - there are spikes when logged in, not when logged out. My server's running a Xeon E3-1225 @ 3.2 so was quite surprised. So it's sounding like the delay is in the page generation server side? I've done most of the reccs: PHP7; Wincache enabled; FastCGI etc. Any ideas? Is there any way to do browser caching with users logged in?